# What is microdata structure or html tags to express developer of site/make reference?

Tags: html, rdf, semantic-web, microdata, schema.org

I want to put some information about developer of site and not know how to do it in HTML or with use microdata or note (i.e. schema.org or other).

Can you share some how to put information about developer (I will be partially author, publisher)?

Comment: What is unclear do you asked any question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the developer is not the publisher/creator/editor/author/contributor of the page/content, you *cannot* use properties of http://schema.org/WebPage nor the [Dublin Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core) vocabulary.

Maybe you could use the properties [`foaf:made`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_made) and/or [`foaf:maker`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_maker) from the [FOAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF_%28software%29) vocabulary. But I’m not sure about it, as they seem to be closely related to [`dc:creator`](http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator), which wouldn’t be appropriate. Maybe have a look at `foaf:currentProject` and `foaf:pastProject`, too.

The [humans.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humans.txt) could be used to informally note any developers/designers etc.